# map rect component array as group of two elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an array of text inputs like

```
var A = [<TextInput ... />, <TextInput ... />, ....]
```

and I want to map these elements group by two elements inside a row.
ie, every two `<TextInput />` wrapped inside a `<Row>` how can I implement this.
I want output like this

```
<Row>
   <TextInput ... />
   <TextInput ... />
</Row>
<Row>
   <TextInput ... />
   <TextInput ... />
</Row>
<Row>
   <TextInput ... />
   <TextInput ... />
</Row>
....
....
```

I tried this code inside the loop but it produce an error.

```
{index % 2 === 0 && <Row> }
      <TextInput {...props} />
{index % 2 === 1 ? </Row>}
```

I think we cannot return Closing tag of `</Row>` only inside jsx

Comment: `<Row> { group your two TextInput here} </Row>`

Comment: @Prasanna But how can I done using a single loop

Comment: why do you have an array of input components

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. There can be errors though, I have not tested this yet

```
<div> 
  {
    A.map((_, index) => 
      (index % 2 === 0) && 
      <Row> 
       {A[index]} 
       {A[index+1] ? A[index+1] : <div />} 
      </Row>
    )
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var A = [ < TextInput .../>, <TextInput ... / >,...]

    let arrTwoComp = [],
        arrComp = [];
    A.forEach((oneComp, key) => {

        arrTwoComp.push(oneComp);

        if ((key + 1) % 2 === 0) {
            arrComp.push(
                <Row>{arrTwoComp}</Row>
            );
            arrTwoComp = [];
        }
    })


    //display arrComp

    <div>{arrComp}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
render() {
  var temp = [], arr = []
  while(A.length){
    temp.push(A.shift())
    A.length && temp.push(A.shift())
    arr.push(temp)
    temp = []
  } // creates array of arrays
  return arr.map(rowOfTwo => 
    <Row>
     {rowOfTwo[0]}
     {rowOfTwo.length > 1 && rowOfTwo[1]}
    </Row>
  )
}
```

basically preform your split :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const A = [<TextInput ... />, <TextInput ... />, ....];
A.map((_, idx) => {
  if (idx % 2 === 0) {                // only do this on 0 and even indexs
    let inputs = [A[idx]];            // we'll always have an item at idx
    const y = A[idx+1];               // but idx+1 may not exist (i.e., idx was the last item)
    if (y) {                          // if idx+1 doesn't exist, it'll be undefined, so let's avoid including it
      inputs.push(y);
    }
    return (
      <Row>                           // return the items (or item) wrapped in a row
        {...inputs}
      </Row>
    );
  }
}).filter(x => x !== undefined);      // map function has to return something, so the odd indexes will return undefined; lets filter them out now
```

A [simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0t7nwvk/) illustrating the functionality via console logging.